# What should List<long[]> method type return?

Tags: java, methods, casting, return, return-type

Can anybody explain what should this type of a method return?

```
public static List<long[]> removNb(long input) {
```

I've been struggling with this one for a long time. In my method, this ArrayList `List<Long>result=new ArrayList<>();` holds the return data, but I can't understand what should return look like as if I try to return, it throws an error `error: incompatible types: List<Long> cannot be converted to List<long[]>` .I've searched the web but did not find anything. I've never seen this List<Long[]> before. What are these [] braces after `long`?
I can't change function prototype as my exercise conditions do not permit it. I've tried creating long array and using Arrays.asList method but it did not help or I used it wrong.

Hope you guys could help me.
Thank you in advance. Peace and love!

Comment: The return type of the method is `List<long[]>`, i.e. a `List` holding `long` arrays.

Comment: The key point: don't mix concepts. Either use array of array, or list of list of long. You probably don't find content about mixing those two things because exactly such mixing is something you really avoid in the real world.

Comment: And when you have code that doesn't work you should have a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a `List` of `long[]`, that is, arrays of the primitive type `long` (don't confuse it with the `Long` wrapper). For example, here's how you can build a valid object with the expected return type:

```
List<long[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
long[] array = new long[1];
array[0] = 42L
list.add(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `[]` denotes a simple array, so `long[]` is an array with `long` elements. `List<long[]>` is a list that stores `long[]` elements, so each element of the list is an array containing `long` elements. So, you need to create your result like this:

```
public static List<long[]> removNb(long input) {
    List<long[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    long[] myLongArray = {input};
    result.add(myLongArray);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<long>` is a list in which each element is of long type.

`List<long[]>` is a list in which each element is an array of long type.

```
List<long[]> list = new ArrayList<long[]>();
long[] arr = new long[] {1L, 2L};
list.add(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is list(List<>) of primitive type long array(long[])

Please refer to the sample example which will give you an idea about the list of long array return type.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListOfLongArray {

    public static List<long[]> removNb(long input) {
        long[] arrayOfLong1={1L,2L};
        long[] arrayOfLong2={3L,4L};
        List<long[]> listOfLongArray=new ArrayList<>();

        listOfLongArray.add(arrayOfLong1);
        listOfLongArray.add(arrayOfLong2);
        return listOfLongArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<long[]> listOfLongArray=removNb(2L);
        for (long[] longs:listOfLongArray) {
            for (Long l: longs) {
                System.out.print(l+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println(); //new line
        }
    }
}
```